# MIPS binary to decimal convert

Tags: assembly, binary, decimal, buffer, mips

I am trying to write a assembly program using MIPS to read a binary number and convert it to decimal format. I am trying to assign the users input into a buffer and do the calculation using a loop. How can I find out end of the binary number to return from the loop? Thank you.

```
    .text
main:

    li $v0, 8
    la $a0, input   #; load the address
    li $a1, 32

    syscall
    addi $sp, $sp, -4
    li $t0, 0
    la t1, input

    lb $t2, 0($t1)
    sw $t2, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, -4
    addi $t1, $t1, 1

    .data
input: .space 32    #; 32 bytes are allocate for input
```

Comment: The end of a string is marked with a null character '\0'

Comment: Thanks. I need to do a comparison to check whether it is the '\0' character. How can I do that? I mean have I use use ascii code?

Comment: Branch if equal to zero?